# автоматические создание f-строк в VSCode по событию

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Мне надо в VSCode сделать так, чтобы в файлах .py при редактировании текста в кавычках, когда я пишу {}, мне ставилась f-строка перед текстом. Примерно так:

'Привет, {}' - тут я ставлю скобки, мне же должно подставить f-строку.
f'Привет {}' - вот так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Установить расширение Pylance (если не установлено)
- В меню Файл->Настройки->Параметры (или просто нажать `Ctrl`+`,`) в поиске набрать autoformat - поставить галочку перед `"When typing a '{' in string, autotamically prefix the string with an 'f'"`